# How should i get array of array in javascript as a single value array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

If a have an array in javascript like:

```
[[2,3,4],"data","payload",[name1,name2,name3]]
```

how should I get all the values as a single array like

Result array should be like this :

```
[2,3,4,"data","payload",name1,name2,name3]
```

Comment: can you use lodash or underscore? `_.flatten`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: No, I don't have these libraries in my code, need something to be done in pure Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use concat() to concatenate all the items in your main array into one big array, which I understand is what you're after :

```
var my2dArray = [[2,3,4],"data","payload",[name1,name2,name3]];
var my1dArray = [];


for(var i = 0; i < my2dArray.length; i++)
{
    my1dArray = my1dArray.concat(my2dArray[i]);
}

console.log(my1dArray); // will be [2,3,4,"data","payload",name1,name2,name3]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can flatten it with `.concat()`.

```js
var data = [[2,3,4],"data","payload",["name1","name2","name3"]];

console.log([].concat(...data));
```

Any Array argument passed to `.concat()` will be flattened into the result.

This also uses the "spread syntax", which is only available in newer engines. Use `.apply()` for legacy support.

```js
var data = [[2,3,4],"data","payload",["name1","name2","name3"]];

console.log(data.concat.apply([], data));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `reduce()` for this.

```js
const array = [[2,3,4],"data","payload",["name1","name2","name3"]]


const flattenedArray = array.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])

console.log(flattenedArray)
```

MDN reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Thanks, Christopher! Liked your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
var array = [
  [2, 3, 4],
  "data",
  "payload",
  ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
]

var newArr = [].concat.apply([], array);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: You are awesome Sumner Evans!